# What can I do to extend lifetime of my usb using Ubuntu full install?

Tags: usb, performance

I've done a full install of Ubuntu onto my 8gb usb stick.  What things can I do to extend the lifecycle of my usb stick?  I need it to be the full install, the live versions no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a USB flash drive, then you shouldn't make swap partition on it. Also don't hibernate your computer, as that will write all memory to the USB drive. You could edit your `/etc/fstab` and add "noatime" as that will decrease the number of writes to the flash. Press Alt-F2 or open a terminal, type `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` and change the line which contains your `/` drive:

`# / was on /dev/sdX2 during installation`

`UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXX /               ext4    errors=remount-ro, 0       1`

to include `noatime` so it's like this:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXX / ext4 errors=remount-ro,noatime 0 1
```

This way, there are no writes to the drive when you acces a file (noatime stands for "no acces time") to write the time of the last read.

Comment: One remark:    
Using noatime can cause issues with some programs, most notable example being mutt. If you encounter problems, you can instead use the "relatime" option: http://goo.gl/ftmUL

Comment: I just looked it up and it seems your right. Though mutt isn't quite a program everyone is using. I have "noatime" on my SSD and I haven't encountered any problems so far.

Comment: If you don't have a swap partition, there's nowhere to write the memory so you can't hibernate.  Of course, if you do have swap, using it for hibernation is going to use maybe 1/100,000th of the lifespan of the flash, so not really worth worrying about.

Comment: Ah, another thing that just came to my mind: If you have enough RAM, consider putting /tmp on tmpfs. By this, you avoid that every temporary file is written to the disk.